# Summing Results in a Table for Repeated Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, counting, distinct-values

I'm currently in a tricky situation that I have been unable to figure out, and I was hoping you all might be able to help me solve my issue below:

I have a data set that includes a large amount of columns, however I am only going to show the columns pertinent to my issue (and I renamed them and put them in an excel doc).

What I am trying to do is develop a SQL query to calculate the total amount of PASS results and then the amount of FAIL Results for a given House Name. Each Result corresponds with a specific Resident ID and each Resident ID corresponds with a specific House Name/House ID. Unfortunately, the value Room ID needs to be in this data set, and each unique Room ID also corresponds with a specific House Name/House ID. Therefore, for every unique Room ID that exists for a given House Name, the Resident ID is being repeated.

For Example, if there are 7 Room IDs associated with a specific House Name/House ID, each unique Resident ID associated with that specific House Name/House ID will be repeated 7 times, once for every unique Room ID. Therefore, the Results are also all repeated 7 times. I have attached an example of what the data looks like below.

Note: Not all the data is included here. There are a few more rows to the AAAAAA data not shown, and there are a number of other House Names/House IDs.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and your current attempt would all help.

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you just need to GROUP BY House ID.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is GROUP BY.

Without looking at your data it is hard to come up with the exact query but i have created some test data.

```
create table House (HouseId int, HouseName nvarchar(max));
insert into House (HouseId, HouseName) values (1,'House A'), (2, 'House B'), (3,'House C');

create table Room (RoomId int, RoomName nvarchar(max), HouseId int);
insert into Room (RoomId, RoomName, HouseId) 
values 
  (1,'Room 1 in house A', 1), (2,'Room 2 in house A', 1),
  (3,'Room 3 in house B', 2),(4,'Room 4 in house B', 2),
  (5,'Room 5 in house C', 3),(6,'Room 6 in house C', 3)

create table Resident (ResidentId int, ResidentName nvarchar(max), RoomId int, Result int);
insert into Resident (ResidentId, ResidentName, RoomId, Result)
values 
-- House A = 4 passed, 0 failed
(1, 'Resident 1 in Room 1', 1, 82), (2, 'Resident 2 in Room 1', 1, 76),
(3, 'Resident 3 in Room 2', 2, 91), (4, 'Resident 4 in Room 2', 2, 67),
-- House B = 2 passed, 2 failed
(5, 'Resident 5 in Room 3', 3, 60), (6, 'Resident 6 in Room 3', 3, 64),
(7, 'Resident 7 in Room 4', 4, 28), (8, 'Resident 8 in Room 4', 4, 42),
-- House C = 3 passed, 1 failed
(9, 'Resident 9 in Room 5', 5, 99), (10, 'Resident 10 in Room 5', 5, 57),
(9, 'Resident 11 in Room 6', 6, 75), (10, 'Resident 12 in Room 6', 6, 38)
```

Then your query would look something like:

```
select
  HouseName,
  [Passed] = SUM(x.Passed),
  [Failed] = SUM(x.Failed)
 from
   Resident re
   outer apply (
       --// Logic to determine if they passed or failed
       --// I arbitrarily chose the number 50 to be the threshold
      select [Passed] = case when re.Result >= 50 then 1 else 0 end,
       [Failed] = case when re.Result < 50 then 1 else 0 end
    ) x
   inner join Room r on r.RoomId = re.RoomId
   inner join House h on h.HouseId = r.HouseId
  group by
    h.HouseName
```

here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30894/1

Comment: Hey Tom,

Thanks! I tried a few times to add my data to the question but everytime it wouldn't actually show up. I will definitely try this out and thanks for the taking the time.